# java web start fails with "request message"

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit, java-web-start, windows64

I cannot run the following command:

```
<_path-to-32-bits-java-version-6_>javaws URL
```

I have 64 bits Java 7 installed, and 32 bits Java 6, but no 32 bits Java 7.
The URL gives a JLNP-file that specifies J2SE version 1.7+.

Two errors occurs. Sometimes, an error message pops up with the text:

```
Cannot start the application (SysExec). Etc.
```

Other times, a message displays "Request JRE 1.7+", and a second message:

```
Error: ... Java Web Start cannot download and install the requested version automatically... Etc.
```

Since the JNLP-file specifies version 1.7+, and I have Java 7 installed, it really should work.

Comment: What happens if you try with _<path-to-64-bits-java-version-7>_ javaws URL ? Possibly the 32bit Java 6 can not see the 64bits java 7. I recognize the issue but have no solution from the top of my head...

Comment: The path-to-64-bits-java-version-7> javaws URL works ok. Probably, as you say, the 32 bits Java 6 cannot "see" 64 bits Java 7.

Comment: *"Since the JNLP-file specifies version 1.7+, and I have Java 7 installed, it really should work."*  I like your optimism! :) But no, Oracle decided they weren't going to bother with the possible security problems in earlier versions of the JRE, so decided in recent times to (quietly) drop the ability to run apps. with an earlier Java version.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, that's interesting, do you have a source for that information?